# Как добавить Build status (build/passing) для собственного проекта на Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, build

Возможно ли в Bitbucket иметь build status для тестирования pull, commit, etc. команд? Как можно интегрировать это в репозиторий?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что вы хотите сделать? Билд проекта на сервере и команды гита - как связаны?

Comment: Нужно так чтобы в Bitbucket было видно build status.

Comment: А вам принципиально, чтобы репозиторий был на битбакете?

Comment: Она уже там находится ))

Answer (score 3):

В **bitbucket** собирать проекты и прогонять тесты можно при помощи плагина - **bitbucket pipelines**. Сейчас этот плагин находится на стадии бета тестирования, поэтому требует "инвайта". на странице https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines проекта просто оставляете запрос. Получаете инвайт на почту. Не слышал, чтобы они кому-то отказывали. Мне ответ пришел меньше чем через сутки.

[image: В меню выделен bitbucket pipelines]

[image: Пример билда]

настройка простая

В корень проекта бросаете скрипт сборки **bitbucket-pipelines.yml**, который отрабатывает на каждый пуш.

Например:

```
# You can use a Docker image from Docker Hub or your own container
# registry for your build environment.
image: maven:3.3.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn --version
          - mvn clean install
          - mvn test
```

Так же, есть возможность настраивать определенные скрипты на определенные ветки.

Comment: А *где* сборка выполняется? Битбакет свои ресурсы предоставляет или нужно будет ему свои раннеры настроить и предоставить?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Своего ничего кроме скрипта сборки не нужно. На пуш pipelines поднимает докер и запускает в нем сборку. Причем судя по команде запуска docker run -t --entrypoint=/bin/bash --memory=2048m щедро дает 2 ГБ. (может вру, с докером не знаком)

Answer (score 2):

Битбакет - это удаленный git сервер, хранилище репозиториев. В нем нет функции сборки проектов. Для сборки проектов вам нужен build-сервер, который в свою очередь с битбакетом можно интегрировать.

Comment: А примеры этих build-сервер-ов можете сказать, может быть речь идет о jenkins или что то похоже на jenkins?

Comment: да, Jenkins, Hudson, TeamCity - дальше можно гуглить-выбирать еще. Много их :)

Comment: Попробовали реализовать с помощью jenkins, и тест показыват succes, но в почему в bitbucket не показывает Builds, так как на этой фото(добавлено).

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan значок билда - это функция битбакета, и ему кто-то должен сказать о том, что билд прошел. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin

Comment: @Етки это уже понятно, у меня работает jenkins, но как показано на фото у меня в bitbucket не видно эти значки. Почему, что еще нужно добавить?

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan я же дал ссылку на плагин

Comment: @Etki публикуйте ответ )

Comment: @Etki все равно не появляется этот builds в bitbucket.

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan вы установили плагин? Настроили в нём интеграцию со своим репозиторием? На странице плагина есть подробная инструкция.

Comment: @NIck Volynkin Да все как есть, но кажется что то я упустила.

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan тогда читайте логи сборки на дженкинсе. Если он не может установить соединение с битбакетом, там будет сообщение об ошибке. У вас дженкинс 1 или 2 версии?